How to add Entra ID Auth to internal static website?
I am creating a static website with a SSG. This is intended to be hosted in-house at first; only potentially later in the cloud. The customer uses Entra Id, and only specific user groups should be able to access the application.
I imagine that the web server (nginx, apache2, ...?) checks if the user is logged in, redirects to the AAD sign-in page if not, and maintains the session of the user.

First, I thought about nginx, but it seems like this is only available in the paid version, nginx plus.
Secondly, another answer here redirected to https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy. This seems nice, but I would prefer something packaged, which makes updates easier.
Third, Apache with https://github.com/OpenIDC/mod_auth_openidc might be an option. The documentation is not really detailed and does not look like plug & play either.

I just want to have a professional authentication system in front of a simple, static web app. How can I implement that in an easy, maintainable way?

LEVEL 1
The simplest option would be to host the content behind a reverse proxy or API gateway which provides your external URL. Then use a gateway plugin or utility component that runs in front of your site.
These components tend to be cloud native though, so the ease of use might depend on your deployment model. Eg oauth2-proxy could be deployed using a Docker container:
quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:latest

Another option might be to integrate OIDC logic into a content delivery network. There are online articles about this approach from cloud providers, eg Azure CDN or AWS CloudFront.
LEVEL 2
The fact that you need to secure your app suggests it might not be static content. OAuth should enable you to separate concerns like this, but that might be a longer term objective:

SSG is used for prerendered unsecure data
Web static content is deployed to a CDN and is not secured
APIs manage secured data
APIs are hosted behind a gateway
Your web app is security aware and interacts with APIs to get secure data and dynamically update the page
Your web app runs its own OAuth flow against an authorization server. to get a credential with which to call APIs
You use your own authorization server, which can connect to Entra ID for customer 1 users, or work differently for other customers

This may be overkill for your current objectives. But this type of setup enables scalability to handle additional security use cases.
